# How can I achieve this custom App Bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, styling

[image: UI Example]

I tried to achieve this specific app bar but didn't succeed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Don't go for an AppBar for this kind of design. Instead, create a CustomPainter . Check this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html

Comment: Thank you for your tips! I'll try to use the CustomPainter class for this specific look.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.